# Undefined function 'log' for input arguments of type 'uint8'

Tags: matlab, input, arguments, undefined

i have been trying generate an image.

```
C1 = imread(InputImage);
NumberOfGrayLevels=32;
I= 0.299*C1(:,:,1)+0.587*C1(:,:,2)+0.114*C1(:,:,3);
C = 0;
I=(C*log(I+1))';
new=uint8(mat2gray(I)*(NumberOfGrayLevels-1));
[m,n]= size(new);
rgb = zeros(m,n,3);
rgb(:,:,1) = new;
rgb(:,:,2) = rgb(:,:,1);
rgb(:,:,3) = rgb(:,:,2);
new = rgb/256;
imshow(new,[]);

no9=figure;
image(new);
```

the error is showing at I=(C*log(I+1))';..can you tell me how to solve this?

Comment: What language is this? Please replace one of your tags with the appropriate language tag.

Answer (score 3):

Most probably `C1` is of type `uint8`. You should convert it, i.e.:

```
C1 = imread(InputImage);
C1 = double(C1);
NumberOfGrayLevels = 32;
I = 0.299*C1(:,:,1) + 0.587*C1(:,:,2) + 0.114*C1(:,:,3);
.....
```

if you don't convert `C1` to `double`, then `I` will also be of type `uint8` - it will not contain what you want and `log` function will not work with it.