# How can calculate the not scalar in Mablab?

Tags: matlab

I'm looking for a method about the power calculation in Matlab.
The code like s following

```
Corrected = 255 * (Image/255)^(1/2.2)
```

but as you can see this, this make an error like this:

```
Error using ==> mpower
error happened like this. Integer can only be raised to positive integra powers
```

So what can I do fix it?

Comment: Use `Corrected = 255 * (Image/255).^(1/2.2)` instead?

Comment: @Divakar Yep, the image values are not integer the real numbers. So I want to know another ways

Comment: you forgot about `/255`. `Image` is not a scalar. So all operators should be  array (with `.` preceding).

Comment: @qazi Convert `image` to `double()` and then use the equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Corrected = 255 .* exp((1/2.2) .* log(double(Image./255)))
```

Check [power via logarithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Powers_via_logarithms) and [log not defined for type uint8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904030/undefined-function-log-for-input-arguments-of-type-uint8)

Comment: Yep, I found the way as your recommend, I would have to do like this. log(double(Image))

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I corrected the original answer once again

Comment: Hi both of them equations are totally different.

Comment: I mean that your equation  results and  Use Corrected = 255 * (Image/255).^(1/2.2)  are different.

Comment: I mean that I need to approximation methods  instead of using log or exp functions.

Comment: Seems to be completely out of scope of question initially asked. You mean you are forced to solve the problem using approximation methods?

Comment: Yes Slatin, do you know what approximation methods?  I have just made new question regarding that but I have down vote 2 already .

Answer (score 0):

Im not completely sure what you are asking but, try using the . operator 
so do .^ instead of ^

Comment: Also error happened like this. Integer can only be raised to positive integra powers.

Comment: use combination of `log` and `exp`

Comment: @KirillSlatin How can I fix it?

Comment: mmm how do you use matlab if you don't know basic math? In your case should be something like `Corrected = 255 .* exp((1/2.2) .* log(Image ./ 255))`

Comment: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Powers_via_logarithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Powers_via_logarithms)

Comment: @KirillSlatin thanks but it still have error like this. : undefined function or method 'log' for input argument of type 'uint8'.

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904030/undefined-function-log-for-input-arguments-of-type-uint8). You need to convert your Image using `double()`